# Finding key phrases in strings: PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, stripos

The issue: I need to check a string for key phrases and if it contains those phrases, assign to a certain tag name.

I'm working in WordPress with PHP.

The code that I've created so far is:

```
/* WOMENS SPORTSWEAR TAGS */
function map_womens_sportswear_tags( $tag_name ) {
$tags = array(
    'Womens Tracksuit Pants' => array( 
        'Tracksuit Pants', 
        'Sweatpants', 
        'Shell Pants',
        'Jogger Pants',
        'Jogging Bottoms', 
        ), 
    'Womens Tracksuit Jackets' => array( 
        'Tracksuit Jacket',
        ),
    'Womens Fleece Jacket' => array(
        'Fleece', 
        ),
    );

foreach( $tags as $tag => $values ) {
    $current_tag = $tag; // Current tag is the name of the tag, like Womens Sports Shoe or Womens Tracksuit Pants
    foreach( $values as $value ) {
        if ( strtolower( $value ) == strtolower( $tag_name ) || stripos( $tag_name, $current_tag   ) ) {
            return $current_tag; // Returns tag name, i.e. 'Womens Sports Shoe' or 'Womens Tracksuit Pants'
            break;
        }
    }
}
return $tag_name;
}
```

Therefore, if a string contains the words Jogging Bottoms, assign to Womens Tracksuit Pants. I've used stripos for this purpose, however I can't get the code to work.

Please could someone point me in the right direction as I'm new to coding. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: After the first encounter of a tag you are using `return` which returns the `$current_tag` from the function. If I understand correctly, you should put the tags into an array and return the whole array at the end of function.

Comment: is no point in using break after return, the statement will be unreachable. Use this for second param in  if (stripos() !==false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you just mixed up your variabled in the if statement:

```
if ( strtolower( $value ) == strtolower( $tag_name ) || stripos( $tag_name, $current_tag   ) ) {
```

should be

```
if ( strtolower( $value ) == strtolower( $tag_name ) || stripos( $tag_name, $value   ) ) {
```

Comment: Thanks all - and particularly A.L.

Comment: Your edit worked perfectly on the test I did just now.

Comment: I've clicked the check mark at the side of your answer. Assume this is all I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you are searching for a tag that match with the `$tag_name` passed to your function.
In your stripos (if i'm right) you have [inverted parameters](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php): 
1. the string 
2. your key word to find in the string

Check if the result is `!== false` because with just a simple if, a result of 0 (at the first occurence of the string) that will return false ([See the red section in the doc](http://us.php.net/manual/fr/function.strpos.php)).

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
foreach( $tags as $tag => $values ) {
    $current_tag = $tag; // Current tag is the name of the tag, like Womens Sports Shoe or Womens Tracksuit Pants
    foreach( $values as $value ) {
        if ( strtolower( $value ) == strtolower( trim($tag_name) ) || stripos( trim($tag_name), $current_tag   ) ) {
            return $current_tag; // Returns tag name, i.e. 'Womens Sports Shoe' or 'Womens Tracksuit Pants'
            break;
        }
    }
}
```